# Opencart URLs and App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, opencart

I want to transfer my opencart application to Google App Engine. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to translate the SEO URLs into routes for App engine. I have the home page working but for URLs such as http://www.site.com/{parameter} or http://www.site.com/{parameter}/{parameter}, I cannot figure how to catch the parameter and figure out where to route it in the app.yaml file. Any help would be great!

Comment: I don't know anything about opencart, but generally you do most of the routing inside the app itself: app.yaml is only for the very basic groups, ie to distinguish between asset urls and the different apps, and you forward the URL to the app itself to do the parameter routing.

Comment: I don't know anything  about Google App Engine (yet), but generally You can use the SEO URL engine that is in OpenCart directly. Then (after turning the SEO URLs on in administration and filling in the SEO keyword for products, categories, manufactureres, information pages) You can have URLs like `http://myopencartdomain.com/mycategory/mysubcategory/myproduct/` or `http://myopencartdomain.com/this-is-about-us-page/`. If *GAE* allows such routes (or You can configure them this way) then You have won.

Comment: Anyway, according to [Docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/?csw=1) the PHP is only *experimental* yet, so maybe it would be better (wiser) to wait for a little until it is 100% working...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But I already have known the advice you all gave. Any URL that uses index.php?route={route} works fine. Its just the SEO urls that were already created in the past that I cant figure out where to route them to in able to parse them from the info in the database.